# SQL error (ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a database that I have made on phpmyAdmin that consists of three columns: id, name and number. 
I have added 3 rows of data to the database through phpmyadmin. 
I now wish to add data to this database through my php file. This is the code that I use to add in the data and display the data on the browser:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "myfirstsite";

// Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
echo "wooo connected";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO hi (id, name, number)
VALUES ('99', 'Doe', '999999')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}


//displaying data
$sql = "SELECT id, name, number FROM hi";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " " .                    $row["number"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The thing is that I don't understand why the new data isn't placed into the database but the current data is displayed onscreen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are making reference to `$link` which doesnt exists, it should be `$conn`

**Chaneg this:**

```
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

**To:**

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to fix this one

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

to

```
$conn = new mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

and also this need to fix

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
     echo "Records inserted successfully";
}else{
     echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: A little explanation goes a long way to help people understand the why behind the answer.

Comment: This answer is very wrong. `new mysqli_connect` is completely wrong.